# How to split log for each services deployed on wildfly?

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

we have about 14 war (spring 4) deployed on a wildfly cluster.
we want that each war write in a different log file.
War1.war -> war1.log
War2.war -> war2.log
...
War...N.war -> war...N.log

someone can help me on this?
thanks

Comment: You mean external configuration?

Comment: https://docs.wildfly.org has some documentation on this. You could use a configuration file for each WAR or you could use something like logging profiles.